# JQuery width method -prevent page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the width() method to change the css when width of window is changed, but the code is working only after each page refresh. Is there a way to do this without page refresh?

```
`var mod= $(window).width();
 $(window).resize(function(){
   if(mod< 800){
        $(".information").css({"color":"green"});
     }
   else{    
        $(".information").css('color','yellow');
     }
 });
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mod` variable is being defined outside your resize event handler, and as such is only ever updated once when the page first loads.

Move it inside the event handler.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   var mod = $(window).width();

   if(mod < 800){
        $(".information").css({"color":"green"});
     }
   else{    
        $(".information").css('color','yellow');
     }
 });
```

To have it work on both load, and resize, move it to a separate function. Use this function as the event handler, and call it once as the page loads.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/zazepubati/1/edit?html,js,output)</kbd>

```
function size() {
   var mod = $(window).width();

   if(mod < 800){
        $(".information").css({"color":"green"});
     }
   else{    
        $(".information").css('color','yellow');
     }
}

$(window).on('resize', size);

size();
```

Comment: Thanks it is working now. I have spent hours to fix, but didn't figure out such simple mistake